# Defining an agent lazily

Tags: clojure

I am creating an agent for writing changes back to a database (as discussed in the agent-based write-behind log in [Clojure Programming](http://www.clojurebook.com/)).

This is working fine, but I am struggling to create the agent late. I don't want to create it as a def, as I don't want it created when my tests are running (I see the pool starting up when the tests load the forms even though I use with-redefs to set a test value).

The code I started with is (using c3p0 pooling):

```
(def dba (agent (pool/make-datasource-spec (u/load-config "db.edn"))))
```

I tried making the agent nil, and investigated how I could set it in the main of my application, when it's really needed. But there doesn't seem to be an equivalent `reset!` function as there is with an atom. And the following code also failed saying the agent wasn't in error so didn't need restarting:

```
(when (not @dba)
  (restart-agent dba (create-db-pool)))
```

So at the moment, I have an atom containing the agent, where I then do:

```
(def dba (atom nil))
;; ...
(defn init-db! []
  (when (not @dba)
    (log/info "Creating agent for pooled connection")
    (reset! dba (agent (create-db-pool))))
```

But the very fact I'm having to do `@@dba` to reference the contents of the agent (i.e. the pool) makes me think this is insane.

Is there a more obvious way of creating the pool agent lazily?

Answer (score 3):

`delay` is useful for cases like this. It causes the item to be created the first time it is read. so if your tests don't read it it will not be created.

```
user=> (def my-agent (delay (do (println "im making the agent now") (agent 0))))
#'user/my-agent
user=> 
user=> @my-agent
im making the agent now
#object[clojure.lang.Agent 0x2cd73ca1 {:status :ready, :val 0}]
```

Comment: this is interesting, but still requires double dereferencing to get to the item, e.g. `(def a (delay (agent 0)))`, then `@a => #<Agent@14c657f9: 0>`, and `@@a => 0`. Is that normal? I don't think I've ever seen `@@` used in anyone's code I've viewed so it feels like i'm missing a trick. However, this does reduce my code from needing an explicit check/reset!, so is better in that respect.